# Error opening InputStream USB Microphone and Raspberry PI3B+

Tags: python, usb, microphone

I am trying to use a USB microphone with python sound device and raspberry pi3B+. When I execute the script in the console typing $ python3 sound.py it runs and records all ok. But when I try to execute `sudo python3 sound.py` it returns the error:

```
Error opening InputStream: Invalid sample rate [PaErrorCode -9997]
Expression 'paInvalidSampleRate' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 2048
```

I need to use sudo to run my script. 
What can I do to solve it?

Thank you!

Comment: What library are you using?

Comment: Hello and welcome - Please add your code. Check [this link](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=241814) out.